# Is there a way to install the .NET 3.5 Framework without rebooting?

Tags: .net

I have been writing a GUI application for rsync on Windows and I have been deploying it to servers.

I have a problem because I use the .NET framework, and server does not have it installed, and the 3.5 framework requires the server to be rebooted after installation. This is not acceptable. Does 2.0 require this same behavior or can I avoid it? If not, is there a way to bypass the forced reboot?

Comment: I've installed .NET 3.5 framework before, told it to "Reboot Later", and tried my application and it worked fine. While it's probably not optimal, have you seen if your app works without the reboot?

Comment: Do you really need to roll your own rsync GUI for windows?  A quick google search turned up plenty of promising ones... maybe some don't depend on .NET.

Comment: None of the others worked the way we wanted, i.e. ssh. It's actually a GUI for rsync and ssh port forwarding and a few other things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.0 is really the thing that requires the reboot. 3.5 is just 2.0 with some things bolted on. You must reboot after installing, otherwise your installation may be incomplete. Can you schedule the installation and reboot to occur at a specific time, when the servers aren't utilized?

Comment: That's possible, I wish .NET allowed static compiling.

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge .NET 2 too requires a restart.
You can install .NET with  -norestart command but that does not mean .NET will not need restart. It will only delay the restart till you decide the machine can be restarted.

Answer (score 1):

I handled a WinServer once, and we had the restart issue pop up often, especially after critical updates.

Most of the functionality of a server can be distributed among two or more servers, and if you set them up right, restarting one could be unnoticeable.

Comment: I'm not in control of these servers and they're often the only serve a business has. If it goes offline, the company will generally grind to a halt until it's back up. The only reason I get to touch them is because my boss finally convinced them they might actually want to do a backup.

Comment: In that case, the users could easily be notified of server reboot via the messaging service and work offline for a few minutes. They could surely be persuaded to accomodate that if it is required.

Answer (score -1):

Rebooting depends on what's installed and running on the server. On clean gold (aka RTM) Win 2003 you shouldn't have reboot, while in a machine with lots of running software it's almost secure to do a reboot.